# Finding out matches between two dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two files 'seen.txt' and 'members.txt'. First file 'seen.txt' lists the people who have seen a post. The file is structured like following:

```
Friend/Not Friend
Name #1
Number of mutual friends

Friend/Not Friend
Name #2
Number of mutual friends
```

Second file 'members.txt' lists the details of the all the people in a group. The file is structured like following:

```
Name #1
Some info about the person
Some more info about the person

Name #2
Some info about the person
Some more info about the person
```

Now, I want to create a program to show the name of the people who are member but not in the seen list. For that, I create two dictionaries which stores the names from each of the files. After it is done, I simply iterate over each member in the members_list and see whether they are in the seen_list or not. If they are not, I print out the name in the console.

This is the code I have written:

```
seen = open('seen.txt').readlines()
members = open('members.txt').readlines()

i = 0
j = 0

seen_list = {}
members_list = {}

for lines in seen:
    if i == 1:
        seen_list[lines.strip()] = 1
        i = 0
    else:
        i += 1

for lines in members:
    if j == 0 or j == 3: # to get the first line and every third line to extract name
        members_list[lines.strip()] = 1
        j = 6
    else:
        j -= 1

for member in members_list:
    if member not in seen_list:
        print member
```

I believe my solution is very elaborate and it can be done in much shorter and faster way. Can anyone tell me about some cool python hacks possible on this program in order to make it more efficient and shorter?

Comment: the file structure is unclear. can you post an example?

Comment: Just an FYI 'cause I see this a lot:  Python's comments use a "#", not a "//".

Comment: Looks like you're reading every other line from seen.txt, but the file structure suggests you should only read the second line after a blank line...

I don't have cool hacks, but you really should use sets here, not dicts, find the intersection between the two, and print all items in the intersection.

Comment: Couldn't you use sets instead of dictionaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use sets instead of dictionaries because it seems like you're throwing away a lot of the stored info in the files and just care about the names.

I first restructured the way you import the names from the files. I used `izip_longest` to read the files 4 lines at a time (3 lines of text plus a blank line).

```
from itertools import izip_longest

seen = set()
with open('seen.txt', 'r') as seen_file:
    for lines in izip_longest(*[seen_file]*4):
        name = lines[1].strip()
        seen.add(name)

members = set()
with open('members.txt', 'r') as members_file:
    for lines in izip_longest(*[members_file]*4):
        name = lines[0].strip()
        members.add(name)
```

Then we just take the set difference. See [set operations here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html).

```
not_seen = members - seen
for member in not_seen: print member
```

Comment: Thank you. This solution is perfect and I learned about sets.

Answer (score 0):

```
seen = open('seen.txt').readlines()
members = open('members.txt').readlines()

i = 0
j = 0

seen_list = set()
members_list = set()

for lines in seen:
    seen_list.add(lines.strip())

for j, lines in enumerate(members):
    if (j==0) or (j%3 == 0):
        members_list.add(lines.strip())

for member in members_list:
    if member not in seen_list:
        print member
```

Comment: those last three lines could just be `print members_list & seen_list`.

Comment: The `&` would give you the intersection. OP wants the difference `members_list - seen_list`.

Answer (score 0):

`members_list` is a dict, so is `seen_list`.

Apparently they carry only one value, 1, and each key has the same value. You can simplify that by using a `set`.

```
members_list = set()
```

and adding items to it:

```
members_list.add(lines.strip())
```

you then have several useful functions on sets, including `difference`:

```
members_not_in_seen = members_list.difference(seen_list)
```

which can also be written

```
members_list - seen_list
```

But you could simplify the reading part: you can use slice and map rather than handle yourself a `i` or `j` counter and call strip on each item:

```
import string
members_list = set(map(string.strip, members[1::2])
seen_list = set(map(string.strip, seen[::4])
```